# How to handle update on image upload

Tags: laravel, file-upload, controller, crud

recently i'm trying to practice with laravel 5.5 and create simple upload and update image

here is my **controller on store**

```
$input = $request->all();


        $this->validate($request, [ 
            'photo' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:500',
        ]);



        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $photo = $request->file('photo');
            $ext = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            if ($request->file('photo')->isValid()) {
                $photo_name = date('YmdHis'). ".$ext";
                $photoName = time().'.'.$request->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->photo->move(public_path('photo-upload'), $photoName);
                $upload_path = public_path('photo-upload');
                $input['photo'] = $photoName;
            }
        }
```

**controller update**

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            // delete the old/previous one
            $exist = Storage::disk('photo')->exists($student->photo);
            if (isset($student->photo) && $exist) {
                $delete = Storage::disk('photo')->delete($siswa->photo);
            }

            // upload new one
            $photo = $request->file('photo');
            $ext = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $photoName = time().'.'.$request->foto->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if ($request->file('photo')->isValid()) {
                $upload_path = 'photo-upload';
                $request->file('photo')->move($upload_path, $phptpName);
                $input['photo'] = $iphotoName;
            }
        }
```

the store method works perfectly, it uploaded image to the right folder then update the databse

the problem is on the update, it update the database but it didn't upload the image to the photo-upload folder

Any suggestion?

Thanks